# justify content isnt working with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a sticky navbar. But I cant change the position to `fixed`. When position is fixed, `justify-content` isn't working anymore.

```css
.nav{
      background: transparent;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 70px;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .nav.sticky{
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
without fixed
<nav id="nav" class="nav">
       <div class="one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
       <div class="two"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
       <div class="three"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
    </nav>
    
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    with fixed

    <nav id="nav" class="nav sticky">
           <div class="one"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
           <div class="two"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
           <div class="three"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
   </nav>
```

Comment: can we see the HTML?

Comment: if you wanna make it sticky, use position: sticky. But need to see more content (HTML) to help.

Comment: sticky doesnt work eather

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: first of all, I don't think position: sticky works with display: flex.  if you are using sticky though you also have to define a top value as I assume your nav is at the top. Also, what is ```.nav.sticky``` for since I dont see it in your html

Comment: the class get created by js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the width of your nav. Justify-content is working, the issue is that there is no space between.

```
.nav{
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 10px;
width: 100vw;
}
.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```
 <nav id="nav" class="nav sticky">
       <div class="one"><img src=""></div>
       <div class="two"><img src=""></div>
       <div class="three"><img src=""></div>
    </nav>
```